# Why isn't my button style changing?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do a custom button style in my navbar in bootstrap but it's taking on the default styles of the navbar. What I am trying to do is make two buttons in the navbar that say sign up and login. I want them to be in-line with the rest of the menu items but to be "buttons" that have a border with no background. Yet they appear with the btn-primary coloring.

This is the code I am using:

```
.btn.outline {
    background: none !important;
    padding: 12px 12px;
}

.btn-primary.outline {
    border: 2px solid #0099cc;
    color: #0099cc;
}

.btn-primary.outline:hover, .btn-primary.outline:focus, .btn-primary.outline:active, .btn-primary.outline.active, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    color: #33a6cc;
    border-color: #33a6cc;
}

.btn-primary.outline:active, .btn-primary.outline.active {
    border-color: #007299;
    color: #007299;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

I call to it like this:

```
<li>
    <p class="navbar-btn">
        <a href="{{ URL::route('register') }}" class="btn btn-primary outline">Sign Up</a>
    </p>
</li>
```

Can anyone spot what I am doing or missing causing it to ignore my CSS?

Thanks!

Edit: I used the !important in hopes it would override the bootstrap.css

Edit again: here's my navbar code:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home"><img src="Landing/img/logo3.png" class="img-responsive2"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right mainnav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#services">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p class="navbar-btn">
                            <a href="{{ URL::route('register') }}" class="btn btn-primary outline">Sign Up</a>
                        </p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p class="navbar-btn">
                            <a href="{{ URL::route('login') }}">Login</a>
                        </p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

Comment: Have you checked thw runtime CSS of these buttons? Often there are some minor changes that are unapparent in the first place.

Comment: @bash.d what exactly do you mean the runtime?

Comment: When you check it in your browser's debugger when the page was loaded.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? And check your css, there are double definitions, e.g. for .btn-primary.outline:active there are two color definition. Which one will you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's working to me using BS 3.3.4.

I grabbed the default navbar code from the BS website and placed yours into it. [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timgavin/5h9h986e/) - it's a button with no background and a blue border.

Perhaps you have some things in the wrong place?

```
<style>
    .btn.outline {
        background: none !important;
        padding: 12px 12px;
    }

    .btn-primary.outline {
        border: 2px solid #0099cc;
        color: #0099cc;
    }

    .btn-primary.outline:hover, .btn-primary.outline:focus, .btn-primary.outline:active, .btn-primary.outline.active, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
        color: #33a6cc;
        border-color: #33a6cc;
    }

    .btn-primary.outline:active, .btn-primary.outline.active {
        border-color: #007299;
        color: #007299;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    </style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <p class="navbar-btn">
                    <a href="{{ URL::route('register') }}" class="btn btn-primary outline">Sign Up</a>
                </p>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and help. I have my code in what appears to be how you did it. The button styling is the very last line of my very bottom CSS file, so it seems like it should be overriding anything before it.

Comment: what happens if you move the button styling right into the `<head>`? Also, what version of BS are you using? Perhaps you should post your `navbar` code...

Comment: what's in the `.mainnav` class? You have that attached to the `<ul>`. Is it overriding your style?

Comment: @timgaving .mainnav is just custom link styling. such as .mainnav a:visited{#666;}

Comment: what happens when you remove it? That class is the one thing I see that's different between your code and the default BS code. Have you styled any other BS code that could be interfering? Obviously what you did works, you just have something else interfering with it...

Comment: I am at the point that I may just start fresh on my nav because I think you're right and something is interfering. I removed .mainnav as I have that overridden anyway and forgot it was still in-place. It made no difference and appears to be the only thing that could be interferring. I believe the next best step is starting all nav html/css code over since there isn't a ton. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Bring your button CSS into the `<head>` and try a different version of BS - whether linked locally or via CDN, and see if that clears it up.

Comment: i added it to the <head> and it's working now. Thank you! Time to figure out what's going on in my CSS. Now I get to deal with the margin between my two bordered buttons that refuses to occur. Haha.

Comment: Good luck with it! :)